# punch through all DOM elements to display content underneath

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm developing on a platform where all video content is displayed on it's own layer, and all DOM elements are drawn on top of it.

I have a full-screen background image which completely covers the video layer but I need to be able to punch a transparent window through this background so that the video layer underneath is visible.  I have to do this on numerous screens so pre-cutting the hole into the background is the least desirable option.

I've tried drawing a div on top with various transparency, opacity etc. but nothing works.

Is this possible with html\css\javascript\a special image with transparency etc?

Comment: Have you tried using 4 divs, top, left, bottom and right?

Comment: No.  I need to be able to place the video window at arbitrary screen positions.